# Wait for Bluetooth audio to start on Android

Tags: android

We have a voice communications app that needs to play audio via bluetooth when a call starts.

We are using [AudioManager.startBluetoothSco](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#startBluetoothSco()) to start the bluetooth, and we are waiting for the [ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED) broadcast intent to change to SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED before playing audio.

However waiting for ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED only delays our start by 150 ms and it takes about 2 seconds before audio starts playing, during this time any audio played just disappears it isn't played out on any device, it isn't delayed it's just gone.

Is there a way to wait for the bluetooth device to be ready to play audio, so that we don't lose the start of our audio?

We also tried using a self managed [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) following the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) set the audio route to bluetooth and waited for the CallAudioState to change, but this had exactly the same problem.

Comment: I just want to confirm that you are listening for `SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED`, as opposed to `SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING`.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 Just double checked I'm definitely waiting for SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED